# How implement an abstract controller that runs concrete actions implemented in modules, depending of vars passed via params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I do need an abstract controller to redirect actions "create" and show executions implemented via Modules, according to vars passed via params eg.:

```
    class Indicator::AbstractController < ApplicationController

    # it doesn't work here.
    # I know here is the class definition, so I can't access instance vars like "params"

      include ConcreteController1 if params[:resource_type_id].eql?(1)
      include ConcreteController2 if params[:resource_type_id].eql?(2)


      # this controller doesn't implements "crate" action
      # this controller doesn't implements "show" action

      # I've tryied implement the "create" and "show" actions and inside then, redirect it's executions to concrete modules, but it doesn't worked
    end

    Module ConcreteController1
      def create
        # special craete method for controller1
      end

      def show
        # special show method for controller1
      end
    end


    Module ConcreteController2
      def create
        # special craete method for controller2
      end

      def show
        # special show method for controller2
      end
    end
```

I've tryied convert these modules into classes ConcreteController < ApplicationController and do the redirection via routes, but I can't figure it out how it could work as I have a variable number of concrete controllers.

We are using a Rails 3.2 application in this case.

Comment: Do you want to run create with a set of parameters passed via a GET, for example, and auto fill them in the form?

Comment: You can add a `boo = params[:boo_params]` in `create` which it would GET from like a link somewhere, `some_path(boo_params: 'boo_value')`, if it is clicked